# Why unidirectional OneToMany inserts null in foreign key?

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I want that my HistoryEntry Entity holds the id of the Project Entity as foreign key.
JPA saves null as foreign key and i dont understand why.

```
public class Project extends BaseModel {

  @Column 
  private String name;

  @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, orphanRemoval = true)
  @JoinColumn(name = "project_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
  private List<HistoryEntry> history;
}
```

```
public class BaseModel {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(generator = "system-uuid")
  @GenericGenerator(name = "system-uuid", strategy = "uuid")  
  @Column(name="id")
  private String id;

  @Column
  @CreationTimestamp
  private LocalDateTime created;

  @Column
  @UpdateTimestamp
  private LocalDateTime updated;
}
```

```
public class HistoryEntry extends BaseModel {

  @Column(name = "project_id")
  private String projectId;
}
```

i save my entities with this code:

```
public ProjectDTO createProject(ProjectDTO projectDTO) {
    Project projectEntity = projectRepository.save(Project.builder()
            .announcements(projectDTO.getAnnouncements() != null ? projectDTO.getAnnouncements().stream()
                    .map(dto -> modelMapper.map(dto, Announcement.class))
                    .toList() : null)
            .history(List.of(HistoryEntry.builder()
                    .action(Action.PROJECT_CREATED.getValue())
                    .build()))
            .status(Status.NEW)
            .name(projectDTO.getName())
            .build()
    );

    return modelMapper.map(projectEntity, ProjectDTO.class);
}
```

i tried without success following solutions from other threads:

```
@Column(name = "project_id", nullable = false)
@Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
```

have anyone ideas how the save the foreign key correctly?

Comment: First of all, the `historyEntry` object built does not know about its project. At creation time, adding the `historyEntry` in the the collection of the project is not enough to set the relation from the `historyEntry` to the `project`. Moreover, the relation in this second  direction is not well modelized. There should be a `project` attribute with a `@ManyToOne` on the `historyEntry` and a `mappedBy` annotation attribute pointing on this attribute  on the `@oneToMany` relation  of the `project`.

Comment: As Pierre hints at, you've mapped things wrong and have two writeable mappings to the HistoryEntry table "project_id" column. If you don't set the value in the HistoryEntry.projectId property, you are telling JPA to insert what is there - null - to the column. You have to set it yourself. The other side, the Project.history mapping will also try to set that field, but only after insertions, and only when JPA discovers changed to the Project entity. Since your values conflict (null and the project->history reference) which actually gets in is up to JPA - which is a bad spot to be.